# Converting from unix time string to python date type, Does not convert when CDT is present

Tags: python, date

I have a date time string in this format in python

```
"Wed Mar 20 00:52:54 CDT 2019 20 Mar 2019"
```

I am trying to convert this to python date time format using below code

```
datetime.datetime.strptime('Wed Mar 20 00:52:54 CDT 2019', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

But it gives error as CDT is present in the text. How to handle this problem. I am not sure if CDT will be present for all dates. In both cases i want to convert.

My requirement is only to get the difference in days between this date and now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `CDT` in the format, then calculate the difference between now and that date. Finally print `delta.days`.

```
from datetime import datetime

date0 = datetime.strptime('Wed Mar 20 00:52:54 CDT 2019', "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CDT %Y")
date_now = datetime.now()

delta = date_now - date0

print(delta.days)
```

Output in this case:

```
0
```

If you're not sure if there will be CDT, check the string before passing it to `strptime`. Or use `try/except`:

```
try:
    date0 = datetime.strptime(string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S CDT %Y")
except ValueError:
    date0 = datetime.strptime(string, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S %Y")
```

Comment: Yes i was able to do this. But i was looking for a way to fix this without checking for CDT in each date.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to use optional bits inside `strptime` format, see my edit, I think `try/except` would fit your needs.